# How are NSSets stored in memory and does it make them more efficient

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have always understood that the data in a NSArray is stored contiguously in the memory of the computer(one object after another). My question is how is a NSSet stored? If each object is stored in different places in the computers memory then surly it will be slower than an array?

Cheers

Do NSSets work more like a linked list?

Comment: You should use `NSSet` if you want your object to contain only unique values. Otherwise it is convenient to use `NSArray`.

Answer (score 3):

The storage used by `NSArray` is not documented. And you should not assume that it is the same for all arrays. There is an excellent write up at ridiculousfish.com, [Our arrays aren’t](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/index.html).

If you are wondering what is the fastest with your requirements. You have to do the tests yourself or be more specific about how you intend to use `NSSet`.

Comment: thank for the response. I was just wondering in what scenario you would use a NSSet over a NSArray

Comment: As another poster said, when you want their semantics. De-duplication is one semantic. NSSets also provide set-ish operations like isSubsetOfSet: and intersectsSet:.  NSMutableSet provides – unionSet:, minusSet:, and intersectSet:.  There aren't any operations here that you couldn't theoretically do with an NSArray (i.e. you could traverse an array and remove duplicates, and approximate all these other operations), but NSSet will have the right semantics out of the box.  In short, use it when it's the right tool for the job!

Answer (score 2):

Whether you use an `NSArray` or an `NSSet` should not depend on their performance characteristics but the semantics of what you want to represent.

An `NSArray` is an ordered collection - with no holes - of items accessed by an index. Duplicates allowed.
An `NSSet` is unordered, and cannot store the same object twice.

Without knowing what you want to do, it's difficult to say more.

Comment: I might take this admonition one step further.  Use the collection with the right semantics at first, and then optimize AWAY from that for performance only if necessary.  For instance, if you want a de-duped collection, start with NSSet, and if you find later that a manually-de-duped NSArray outperforms an NSSet, then you can switch to using that.  But start with the choice that makes the most sense, and then divert from sensibility for performance only if empirically necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Create a NSArray is much faster than create a NSSet. But search for all objects in NSSet is much faster than search for all objects in NSArray, especially you are using `indexOfObject:` method to search the NSArray. (You can test it by yourself, 10,000 objects should be enough to show you the difference.)

But when you choosing which should be used, speed is not the most important thing to be considered.

If you want to make sure that one object should be stored ONLY ONCE, use NSSet, otherwise use NSArray, your object will be stored as much times as you insert it. And of course NSArray's objects are ordered.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of NSArray, NSMutableArray, NSSet, NSMutableSet and other collections changes depending on the number of objects in the collection. You will find more details 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2253317/913665) and in this more in depth analysis in this [blog post](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?FoundationCollections).

As @Jean-Denis suggests, you should choose your collection based on their semantics.